# electrum wallet help needed funds missing

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain.info, electrum, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

I have a problem and not sure if it’s a hack or my back up has not worked.

I was sent a laptop replacement and asked to send the old one back on the warranty so I was removing all my stuff across, I first formatted the new replacement laptop put updates and anti-virus on before downloading a new wallet from electrum.org , using my seed (offline) inputted it into the into the downloaded wallet it asked me for my password and started synchronizing. 
Stupidly the day after I reformatted the replacement laptop and when I referred back to the old laptops electrum wallet, there are now 2 transactions from the same date as I tried restoring the wallet. I’ve used electrum and it kept my coins safe for over 2 years but now I’m cleaned out 

I’m finding it hard to understand if it would have been possible for me to somehow to have created a new wallet address and somehow imported the funds from the old seed would this be a possibility 
I have ran some software and it’s found the file Default_wallet on the formatted laptop, do you think it’s worth getting the software to recover the file or is it a waste of time?

I really appreciate anyone’s help on this matter and more then happy to make a donation to if I can get them back.

I can all so provide the block chain link id if needed as says there was 2 transactions at this time this happened

Comment: If you didn't specifically create those transactions, someone else did.

Answer (score 1):

You must have downloaded electrum from a fake site which served you a backdoored version of the program. If you still have access to your browser history I suggest going through it to find out the exact URL you used to download electrum. The official site is at electrum.org and downloads are served via download.electrum.org.

Answer (score 0):

this sucks, happened to me few years ago.

Since the pc had been freshly formated and you installed an av soft, I think that rules out malware in your new system.
I think it's more likely you had malware in the old one and it attacked by pure coincidence after you started working on the new system.

Recovering the wallet file from old computer will not help you. It will have the same data.

You don't own bitcoins, you own the private keys to unlock inputs. If your client report those inputs as sent somewhere you didn't, that means someone else used your keys to sign the transactions. Electrum is stable, this can't be a bug or a wallet corruption issue.

I'm sorry man.

Comment: It doesn't rule out malware. In fact malware is the most likely cause. OP probably downloaded a fake copy of electrum. It's a common problem for people who restore from seed on a new system and don't take the time to make sure they are downloading from the official site.